# Want the output to return an S curve

Tags: python, function, scipy

I want to write a python code, where I need to assign a % value to numbers from 1 to 50, but not linearly.
For, e.g., if I call a number, say, 10, then it should return a % value associated with it. And if I plot all these numbers and their % values, I should get an S curve.
Any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Can you be more specific about this S-curve. Is it like a Sigmoid Function?

Comment: Yes like a Sigmoid function, but all the values need to be positive. I need the value outputs to have the shape of the s curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rescale the sigmoid function to a certain range, you can use the following equation:

```
Sx = 1/(1+exp(-ax+ab));
```

Where `a` is a scaling factor that limits the maximum slope. This can be used to increase the useful range (remember, the standard equation has a useful range roughly between -6 and 6). use `a=6` to scale the function roughly to x= -1 and x = 1. `b` is the offset of the center. this means that if `x=b`, then Sx=0.5. In your situation, I would advice using something like

```
Sx = 1/(1+exp(0.2*(-x+25)));
```

To improve the effect even more, after this, you could subtract the value obtained at x = 0, to ensure that if x=0, Sx = 0. Then, you could divide the entire result by the current function value at x=50. This is to ensure that if x=50, Sx = 1. This does however also mean that for larger values of x, the curve exceeds 1.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a ton for the @Petrus1904, I have the solution that I was looking for because of your comment.

[image]

I wanted to cut down my investment percentage based on the pledge percentage of the promoter of a company, that's what this output is all about.

Thanks.